# CSS: Dropdown borders

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, border

I'm working on a CSS dropdown: http://jsfiddle.net/tMND4/

The problem I am having is for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to set a 2px margin on the lower item + add a border around the dropdown box as per this shot:

The red X is what is currently being produce, the green is what I would like. I have a CSS property to add a margin to the last element but it is not getting applied + nothing seems to. I've tried every combo but I'm stuck!

[image: Nice shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tMND4/2/

have redone a few things and guess what? no JS!

EDIT: added comments and tweaked a few stuff

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get it to display properly outside of JSFiddle. In a blank page I get [this result](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/217/notquiteright.png/)

Comment: ow.. i forgot. add `list-style:none` for all the `<ul>` in that menu. i think JSFiddle has a CSS reset that's why the default bullets didn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tMND4/3/